# Why does the actual body of a closure never gets executed?

Tags: ios, swift

From Apple's Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.2 Beta)

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
       print("Declaring Function")
}

// Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
    // closure's body goes here
       print("Without Trailing Closure Syntax")
})

// Here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
       print("Trailing Closure Syntax")
}
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.2 beta).” Apple Books.

In these examples, it only prints Declaring Function twice when `someFunctionThatTakesAClosure` gets called twice, I'm wondering how the body of the these two closures didn't get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change to the following:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
   print("Declaring Function")
   closure()
}
```